# Python memory error in CPU and wall time

Tags: python

I am trying to do a function to calculate the modular exponential of three variables and compare the CPU and wall time when:

```
e=2^n and e=2^n-1
```

Here is my code:

```
from random import choice
import random
def question_3(m,n):
    list = []
    for i in range(2,2**m):
        flag=True
        for num in list:
            if(i%num==0):
                flag=False
        if(flag):
            list.append(i)
            p = choice(list)
            a = randint(1,int(p)-1) 
            e = pow(2,n)
    return pow(a,e,p)
time t = question_3(150,100)
```

But when I enter m and n with huge numbers, it gives me:

```
range() result has too many items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're forcing `range` to generate too much data. For example, `range(2, 2*1234567891011)` will generate a list with the length of `2*1234567891011-2`, isn't it a bit too much?

Try using `xrange()` instead, it generates the data when needed, instead of making all of the data when you call it.

Change it to this:

```
for i in xrange(2,2**m):
```

Looks simple, but it has a huge difference. Hope this helps!